# Angular-6 router-outlet is not a known element, Template parse errors

Tags: angular6, router-outlet

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {PostListComponent} from './post/post-list.component';
const routes: Routes =  [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'posts', component: PostListComponent},

]
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{
}

**app.component.html**
```

```html
<a routerLink='/posts'>View Posts</a>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please do comment to get related useful code for more help.Thanks

Comment: You forgot the <nav> element that will triggers the navigation. Wrap the <a> with <nav>.

Comment: @jess  `<nav><a routerLink="/posts">View Posts</a></nav>`it's still not **creating a link**,it's only showing text, my issue is with the **`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`**.

Answer (score 0):

I got that i was not importing my **App-routing.module** in my **App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './post/post-list.component';
import { PostService} from './post/post.service';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostListComponent,
    HomepageComponent
  ],
  imports:[
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    **AppRoutingModule**
  ],
  providers: [
    PostService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```